# How do I filter stdout of a program through grep while still controlling the program?

Tags: bash, grep, stdout, stdin

I'm trying to filter the output of the mpv media player, removing a particular line, but when I do so I am unable to control mpv with the keyboard. Here is the command:

```
mpv FILE | grep -v 'Error while decoding frame'
```

When I run the command, everything displays correctly, but I am unable to use the LEFT and RIGHT keys to scan through the file, or do anything else with the keyboard. How do I filter the output of the program while retaining control of it?

Comment: Are you sure `mpv` reads the keyboard if it detects it output is redirected to file? I.e if you do `mpv FILE > somefile.out` can you control it with the cursor?

Comment: @Anthon Oops, it doesn't, so would that imply that the place to look is mpv's settings?

Comment: Maybe there is some commandline switch for `mpv`. Quite a lot of programs actually detect if their output goes to a file (e.g. try `man |  grep -F a` and you will not be able to scroll back and forth).

Comment: @Anthon there's a `--input-terminal` option but no dice, controls still changed, I think this is a dead end. Thanks for the help, though.

Answer (score 7):

You can give mpv a fake terminal by using the script(1) program, for instance:

```
script -c 'mpv FILE' /dev/null | grep -v 'Error while decoding frame'
```

For Mac OS X, [the syntax seems to be](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/script.1.html):

```
script /dev/null mpv 'FILE' | grep -v 'Error while decoding frame'
```

[edit: also check out [Trick an application into thinking its stdin is interactive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1401002/711380) for additional solutions]

Comment: When I try to use script, it doesn't allow a `-c` option... and there's no `--version` option to try to see if its a version issue either. I'm running Mac OS Yosemite.

Comment: Yep, it's different; I added their syntax from the man page

Answer (score 1):

You can use `nohup mpv FILE`. The output is written to `nohup.out` which you can filter using `tail` and `grep`:

```
nohup mpv FILE
tail -f nohup.out |grep -v 'Error while decoding frame'
```

Comment: Tail just hangs waiting for text, even though mpv might have stopped producing output. If this is scripted, how do you detect EOF and exit?

Comment: Love that this way I don't have to stop the ongoing command in order to tweak the grep.